# How do you customize mongodb (mongoid) field names in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm currently trying to customize my error messages and I am not able to change the database table field names to be more readable.

I've tried updating the config/locales/en.yml file but it doesn't change it when the validation error occurs:

```
en:
  mongoid:
    attributes:
      user:
        restaurant_name: "Restaurant Name"
```

MongoDB table: `users`
MongoDB field name: `restaurant_name`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localization is for field values not for field names.

If you are having a trouble getting localization to work with field values it might be because you haven't enabled localization in the model.

If that is the case, simply add `localize: true` to the field definition.